# Can I run a python script on one computer running linux/windows from another computer by calling it?

Tags: python, server, google-cloud-platform

I have a python script on my computer. I want that I can execute this script just by triggering it to start from another computer. Provide the case they can use internet , wifi or even bluetooth for this purpose. Also it is possible to do so using GCP shell?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either use ssh to actually login on your remote computer or set up an API. Such an API could be a small web server.

For testing you could use simplehttpserver https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `firebase`. You can upload some variable into your cloud database from your main computer and which then invokes a desired action upon receiving the data in your side computer. You can [check it out](https://firebase.google.com/). There are many `python` APIs built for it, but it mainly communicates through `httprequests` if im not wrong.

OR, you can set up a vnc viewer/server on your client and main computer.